# Can't get Jquery.val working in MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I know I'm doing something wrong somewhere, could somebody point it out to me?

I have a viewmodel, containing a `CurrentSection` property

```
public String CurrentSection {get; set;}
```

In the view, I call the viewmodel and jQuery

```
@model Application1.ViewModels.fooVM

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Then I do the following (Which works in JSFiddle)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#CurrentSection").val('SecStoreIndex');
    });
</script>

@Html.EditorFor(X => X.CurrentSection)
```

With the EditorFor rendering as

```
<input id="CurrentSection" name="CurrentSection" type="hidden" value="" />
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have multiple `#CurrentSection` elements on the page? Is it appended after page load? Have you included jquery.js? Any errors in the console?

Comment: Just the single element, I have included jquery and no errors in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am holding my hands up and owning up to stupidity.

I was attempting to view the dynamically changed value view viewing the pages source. It suddenly occurred to me this does not show up. I threw in an alert and the value is being changed.

Sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the script that is using jQuery is placed **after** the inclusion of jQuery:

```
@model Application1.ViewModels.fooVM

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#CurrentSection").val('SecStoreIndex');
    });
</script>

@Html.EditorFor(X => X.CurrentSection)
```

Also make sure that inside your `_Layout.cshtml` you don't already have a `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` call and getting duplicate jQuery inclusion.

Also bear in mind that the default template uses Scripts section in the _Layout, so if you have created your application using this default template you should probably place your script inside this section:

```
@model Application1.ViewModels.fooVM

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#CurrentSection").val('SecStoreIndex');
    </script>
}

@Html.EditorFor(X => X.CurrentSection)
```

Also notice that in this case I have removed the `$(document).ready` wrapper because the default template places all scripts at the end of the DOM, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: I've attempted all this but to no avail.

Comment: Could you show your full code? `_Layout.cshtml` and the full code of your view? It's hard to help you without knowing your code. Also it would help to show the generated HTML source code as seen by the browser.